# Start executable passing parameters from Tomcat Service

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, service, process

I need to start an executable (and pass it two parameters) from tomcat running as windows service.

I'm actually using `ProcessBuilder`:

```
new ProcessBuilder("D:\\folder\\startthis.exe", "param1", "param2");
```

This works only if tomcat is started in console, it did not works if tomcat is started as Service.

I tried to change the Run as User of the tomcato service to Local System/Local Service and my account itself

I could also call a ".bat" file it the solution is easier to implement (but the .bat file has to call the executable...)